# How to add service to Angular2 test (CLI config, not as in docs)

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, service

I'm just now learning unit testing in general, but I'm simultaneously learning angular2. Angular CLI created my test scaffolds and I've configured the testing module with the neccessary component and directive. I'm trying to provide a stub service similar to the one decribed in the [DOCS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html), but I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot create the component FoodListComponent as it was not imported
>   into the testing module

This is odd because the `should create` test passed when with the `FoodListComponent` before I added the service into the `providers: []`. My service works fine in the application, but I can provide it too if you need to see it.

**Basically I'd like to know where in this testing set up I need to put the `foodDataServiceStub`, whether I'm adding the stub service to the `TestBed` object correctly, and where I need to inject the service via `foodDataService = TestBed.get(FoodDataService);`?**

I'd be thankful for an explanation as well.

`food-list.component.spec.ts`

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TickerDirective } from '../../directives/ticker.directive';
import { FoodListComponent } from './food-list.component';

describe('FoodListComponent', () => {
  let component: FoodListComponent;
  let fixture:   ComponentFixture<FoodListComponent>;

  let foodDataServiceStub = {
    name: 'test food name',
    img: '',
    description: 'test food description'
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FoodListComponent, TickerDirective ],
      providers:    [ { provide: FoodDataService, useValue: foodDataServiceStub } ], /* This line gives me the error */
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FoodListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // foodDataService = TestBed.get(FoodDataService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Try and get rid of the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA and see if you get a more informative error message.

Comment: to be clear this test passes right? [ with `foodDataService = TestBed.get(FoodDataService);` commented out]. If so then I would try getting the the service from the component provider instead the root injector with `foodDataService = fixture.deBugElement.injector.get(foodServiceStub)`